# Codeignitier mod_rewrite and parent folder

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-url

I am using CodeIgniter and I am trying to remove the index.php from the urls.  I have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache, I set the index to a blank string in the CI config file and I am using the .htaccess file found at the bottom of the page.  I think part of the problem might be that my application and system folders are not in my document root.  My local server folder structure looks like this:

```
mysite.dev/
-public_html (server root)
-application
-system
-.htaccess
```

I did it that way because I read that it would be extra security having the application and system outside of the public_html folder.  But the rewrite rules aren't working and I suspect it has something to do with this.  I'm relatively new to this so I really appreciate any help!

my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#’system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn’t in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename ’application’ to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don’t have mod_rewrite installed, all 404′s
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: for future reference, following these instructions worked http://www.highermedia.com/articles/nuts_bolts/tutorial_advanced_codeigniter_installation

Answer (score 0):

I have used that code in my .htaccess file as it's working for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: it's still not working, if I try to visit  localhost/home I get a 404 error but localhost/index.php/home works.  I tried your htaccess and I reset apache but no luck